# How to identify elements needed for requests in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a web url `https://www.blibli.com/backend/content/promotions/blm-ranch-market`
where when I opened it on chrome returns a json.

However when I tried using requests in python and tried using headers including the cookie from headers it does not work. What is missing?
How do we know what's needed for the request?I check in sources there's no payload only headers, I assumed by this code it will work. However using the same headers does not work.

```py
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://www.blibli.com/backend/content/promotions/blm-ranch-market')
if resp == 200:
    print(resp.json())
```

Comment: You don't show how you tried while using headers... which is obviously where you went wrong... so we can't diagnose what you did wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked fine for me after adding a User-Agent header.

```
import requests

headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

response = requests.get('https://www.blibli.com/backend/content/promotions/blm-ranch-market', headers=headers)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

output:

```
200
{'code': 200,
 'data': {'components': [{'id': '8ab055d680424814018045bccc5e42ce',
                          'name': 'PAGE_ANCHOR_TABBING',
                          'parameters': [{'alt': 'Produk Terlaris',
                                          'id': '8ab055d680424814018045bccc5e42d2',
                                          'image': 'https://www.static-src.com/siva/asset//02_2022/Icon_TBL_musthave.png',
                                          'imageRatio': '1:1',
                                          'isMerchant': False,
                                          'name': 'image_4',
                                          'newTab': False,
                                          'requireLocation': False,
                                          'sequence': 0,
                                          'showProductTag': False,
                                          'sumOfProduct': 0,
                                          'title': 'Produk Terlaris',
                                          'type': 'IMAGE',
                                          'url': 'PROMO_1_BANNER-24',
                                          'use2HdProduct': False},
                                         {'alt': 'Produk Pilihan',
                                          'id': '8ab055d680424814018045bccc5e42d3',
                                          'image': 'https://www.static-src.com/siva/asset//02_2022/Icon_TBL_popular.png',
                                          'imageRatio': '1:1',
                                          'isMerchant': False,
                                          'name': 'image_5',
                                          'newTab': False,
                                          'requireLocation': False,
                                          'sequence': 0,
                                          'showProductTag': False,
                                          'sumOfProduct': 0,
                                          'title': 'Produk Pilihan',
                                          'type': 'IMAGE',
                                          'url': 'PROMO_1_BANNER-26',
                                          'use2HdProduct': False},
                                         {'alt': 'Vouchers',
                                          'id': '8ab055d680424814018045bccc5e42cf',
                                          'image': 'https://www.static-src.com/siva/asset//02_2022/BPD-FEB-ICON-CASHBACK.jpg',
                                          'imageRatio': '1:1',
                                          'isMerchant': False,
                                          'name': 'image_1',
                                          'newTab': False,
                                          'requireLocation': False,
                                          'sequence': 0,
                                          'showProductTag': False,
                                          'sumOfProduct': 0,
                                          'title': 'Vouchers',
                                          'type': 'IMAGE',
                                          'url': 'VOUCHERS_GEN_2-6',
                                          'use2HdProduct': False},
...
```

Comment: hi it work fine usually after the first hit but after a few tries, with waiting for a while, I get 403.  is the http/2 below part of the reason? or something else?

Comment: @Halimstack  No the reason is because the website has security measures in place.  You best bet would be to filter through different proxies and user agents for each request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the contents of the page, you might want to try `resp.content`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because that site does not support HTTP/1.1 and `requests`(and its backend http client, `http.client` in the standard library) does not support HTTP/2.

If you need a HTTP/2 client library, try other library, such as [HTTPX](https://pypi.org/project/httpx/).